# Curves in conic bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, projective-geometry, divisors, conic-bundles

Consider a smooth minimal $3$-fold conic bundle $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^2$. Then $X$ has Picard rank two and consequently also the vector space of $1$-cycles is $2$-dimensional. Then the cone of effective curves of $X$ has two generators. On the other hand if $F = F_1 + F_2$ is a reducible fibers it seems that $F_1,F_2$ should be generators, and there should be another generator coming from a curve $C\subset X$ which is not contracted by $f$. What am I missing here? What are the generators of
the cone of curves of $X$?

Thank you.

Comment: The components of the reducible fibers are parameterized by an irreducible curve, hence they are all algebraically equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

Both $F_1$ and $F_2$ are annihilated by the pullback of the line class of $\mathbb{P}^2$. Moreover, both intersect the canonical class of the conic bundle by $-1$. Therefore, they are numerically equivalent.